# LINQ to SQL InheritanceMappingAttribute propriedade Code

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Qual a finalidade da propriedade `Code` do atributo `InheritanceMappingAttribute`?

A documentação descreve dessa forma:

> This property holds a value that appears in the database table in the `IsDiscriminator` column to indicate which class or subclass this row of data belongs to.

Não sei que propriedade é essa `IsDiscriminator`. O exemplo da documentação é esse:

```
public enum ShapeType
{
    Square = 0, Circle = 1
}
[Table(Name = "Shape")]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = ShapeType.Square, Type = typeof(Square),
    IsDefault = true)]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = ShapeType.Circle, Type = typeof(Circle))]

abstract public class Shape
{
    [Column(IsDiscriminator = true)]
    public ShapeType ShapeType = 0;
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    [Column]
    public int Side = 0;
}
public class Circle : Shape
{
    [Column]
    public int Radius = 0;
}
```

ShapeType é o nome de uma coluna na tabela do banco de dados? Qual a finalidade dessa coluna?

Aqui as docs que estou lendo [doc1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352(v=vs.100).aspx) [doc2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.inheritancemappingattribute(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Aproveitando o tópico, gostaria de tirar outra dúvida.
Os dados contidos nas três classes serão gravados em uma mesma tabela na base de dados?
E se na base de dados, eles estiverem em tabelas separadas? Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha, a seguinte hierarquia `Veiculo`(Pai), `Carro`(Derivada), `Moto`(Derivada) e que no db elas sejam representadas em tabelas separadas, ou seja, uma tabela p/ cada classe, simulando herança através de relacionamento.
Como ficaria?

Comment: Cont.... ^. Quero dizer, como ficaria o código c# LINQ, e não a estrutura das tabelas.

As tabelas eu já tenho prontas.

Answer (score 0):

Está tudo nos links que você postou. A classe `InheritanceMappingAttribute` mapeia uma hierarquia de herança em um `LINQ` to `SQL` aplicativo.

O construtor `InheritanceMappingAttribute()` inicializa uma nova instância da classe `InheritanceMappingAttribute`.

Propriedades

- `Code`: Obtém ou define o valor do discriminador código em uma hierarquia de herança mapeada.
- `IsDefault`: Obtém ou define se um objeto desse tipo no instanciado quando o valor do discriminador não coincide com um valor especificado.
- `Type`: Obtém ou define o tipo da classe na hierarquia.
- `TypeId`: Quando implementada em uma classe derivada, obtém um identificador exclusivo para este `Attribute`.(herdado de Attribute.)

Ao mapear hierarquias de herança, observe o seguinte:

- Todas as classes em uma hierarquia devem ser mapeadas para uma única tabela.
- A tabela para uma hierarquia de herança deve ser declarada no tipo mapeado que está no topo da hierarquia. Você não pode especificar os atributos de mapeamento de tabela em uma classe que é derivada da classe superior.
- Você pode usar uma interface em uma hierarquia, mas LINQ não é mapeado.
- Você pode ignorar uma classe na hierarquia ao mapear classes, mas é possível consultar apenas classes mapeadas.

Para a materialização corretas, valores de código do discriminador devem ser exclusivo e correspondem aos valores no banco de dados. Uma linha com um valor de código do discriminador corresponde exatamente (até mesmo por maiúsculas e minúsculas) cria uma instância da classe usando `IsDefault` definida como `true`.

Sobre a propriedade `IsDiscriminator`, ela obtém ou define se uma coluna contém um valor de discriminador para uma `LINQ` to `SQL` hierarquia de herança. O padrão é `false`.

Quando você usa `true`, esta propriedade identifica o membro da classe que contém o valor do discriminador para uma hierarquia de herança.

Exemplo da [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdiscriminator(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
[Column(Storage="_Title", DbType="NVarChar(30)",IsDiscriminator=true)]
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return this._Title;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Title != value))
        {
            this.OnTitleChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._Title = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Title");
            this.OnTitleChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Sobre a classe Shape: veja estes dois links da documentação: [Class Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape(v=vs.110).aspx) e [ShapeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.vml.shapetype(v=office.14).aspx).